# How to get data from DB (Postgres) in the same order as user input?

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, input

I have a textarea, where users can enter words separated by comma. For each word I get a translation (data) from my postgres-database. The input as well as the translation from the database are then shown in a table.

**My problem:**
I need to keep the order of the user input in my table. But the order changes automatically based on the order of the words in my DB. I tried to use ORDER BY, but I couldn't fix it.

Could someone explain me why the order changes and how to fix it? Thanks a lot!

Here's my code:

```js
const getTranslation = async(req, res) => {
  const params = typeof req.query.word === 'string' ? req.query.word : req.query.word.map((_, index) => `$${index + 1}`);
  console.log(req.query.word);
  
  const rawResults = await pool.query(
    `SELECT "Translation", "Words" FROM "Dictionary" WHERE "Words" IN (${typeof req.query.word === 'string' ? '($1)' : params.join(
      ",")})`,
     typeof req.query.word === 'string' ? [req.query.word] : req.query.word, 
     (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      }
      
      res.status(200).json(result.rows); 
      console.log(result.rows);
      }
  );

  const wordOrder = req.query.word.split(',');
  
  rawResults.sort((row1, row2) => {
      return wordOrder.indexOf(row1.Words) - wordOrder.indexOf(row2.Words);
    })
}

/*terminal console.log(req.query.word) is ['yes', 'no']
terminal console.log(result.rows) is [ {'Translation': 'non', 'Words': 'no'}, {'Translation': 'oui', 'Words': 'yes'}] */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reorder it before sending as response.
Fetch from the DB the key and its translation value, and then apply `sort` on the result.

```js
const getTranslation = (req, res) => {
  const params =
    typeof req.query.word === 'string'
      ? req.query.word
      : req.query.word.map((_, index) => `$${index + 1}`);
  console.log(req.query.word);

  const rawResults = pool.query(
    `SELECT "Translation", "Words" FROM "Dictionary" WHERE "Words" IN (${
      typeof req.query.word === 'string' ? '($1)' : params.join(',')
    })`,
    typeof req.query.word === 'string' ? [req.query.word] : req.query.word,
    (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      }
      const wordOrder = req.query.word.split(',');

      result.rows.sort((row1, row2) => {
        return wordOrder.indexOf(row1.Words) - wordOrder.indexOf(row2.Words);
      });

      res.status(200).json(result.rows);
      console.log(result.rows);
    }
  );
};
```

## EDIT

Pay attention that your code is **async** (DB access is async by nature).
Therefore, you need to sort the results just before you send it to the client (just before `res.status(200).json` call)

BTW, it is better to use some kind of query-builder (like [`knex`](http://knexjs.org/)) instead of building the query manually.

Comment: Thanks! I just edited the code in my question. When I console.log the results I get an array...but even if I use .slice instead of .split I get a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined". Can you help me with that?

Comment: I just added the code in my question. You mean this part?

Comment: Thx a lot. I had to delete .split(',') - "TypeError: req.query.ingredient.split is not a function". I suppose because .split() is used for strings. Now everything works!
For my understanding: we generally don't use async...await for DB queries because it is async by default and the problem I had was probably because I didn't define how the rows have to be returned and the system used the fastest way to do so. Am I right?

Comment: I've removed the usage of `Async & await`, since you are working with callbacks.
The problem with your initial code was due the fact that your code was out side of the async callback.
Btw, consider `knex` as alternative to query building manually.

Comment: I took your tip seriously and tried knex... took "only" 1 day now :D if you're interested in pointing me in the right direction, I would be grateful :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64589169/how-to-rewrite-raw-sql-query-with-knex

Comment: Glad to hear :]